# combine array of array objects into single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, es6-modules

this is my input

```
[
  [
    { jobId: 1, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 2, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 3, requiredNumber: 3, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 4, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 }
  ],
  [ { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 95 } ],
  null
]
```

I have been trying to combine this array of objects into a single array,
i have tried using `.reduce()` but i wasn't successful
and my output was like this

```
[
  { jobId: 1, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 },        
  { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 2, acceptableRate: 80 },        
  { jobId: 3, requiredNumber: 3, acceptableRate: 80 },        
  { jobId: 4, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 }
] [ { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 95 } ] null
```

it was still 2 arrays not a single array

my expected output is

```
[
    { jobId: 1, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 2, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 3, requiredNumber: 3, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 4, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 95 }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array, and then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the objects.

```js
const data=[[{jobId:1,requiredNumber:1,acceptableRate:80},{jobId:2,requiredNumber:2,acceptableRate:80},{jobId:3,requiredNumber:3,acceptableRate:80},{jobId:4,requiredNumber:1,acceptableRate:80}],[{jobId:2,requiredNumber:1,acceptableRate:95}],null];

const out = data.flat().filter(obj => obj);
console.log(out);
```

```js
const data=[[{jobId:1,requiredNumber:1,acceptableRate:80},{jobId:2,requiredNumber:2,acceptableRate:80},{jobId:3,requiredNumber:3,acceptableRate:80},{jobId:4,requiredNumber:1,acceptableRate:80}],[{jobId:2,requiredNumber:1,acceptableRate:95}],null];

const out = data.flat().filter(Boolean);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)` is prettier than `.filter(obj => obj)`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `flat` [flat function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
with a `filter` to filter out all the null [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

It could be even simpler than using `flat` or `reduce`. It could be just this (using the `...` [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)):

```
[
  ...[
    { jobId: 1, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 2, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 3, requiredNumber: 3, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 4, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 }
  ],
  ...[ 
    { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 95 } 
  ]
]
```